# JavaScript Button Text innerHTML not Changing when Clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm relatively new to javascript and am trying to find out why the text content of an element isn't changing when it should. I just want the text content of the '+' to change when clicking the 'click me' button.

The element should change. Why doesn't it work here? A detailed explanation would be very helpful after reading a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196240/setting-innerhtml-why-wont-it-update-the-dom). Thanks for any help.

```js
function change() {
var btnToChange = document.getElementsByClassName("testBtn");

btnToChange.innerHTML = "it changed!";
}
```

```html
<button class="testBtn">+</button>
<button class="testBtn2" onclick="change()">Click to Change</button>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array collection for matching class name from DOM. so in this case use `getElementsByClassName('testBtn')[0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do `document.getElementsByClassName("testBtn")[0];` because `document.getElementsByClassName` will return you the array of elements that match the class, although there is a single element in the DOM. Since you have one element use `[0]`.

```js
function change() {
  var btnToChange = document.getElementsByClassName("testBtn")[0];

  btnToChange.innerHTML = "it changed!";
}
```

```html
<button class="testBtn">+</button>
<button class="testBtn2" onclick="change()">Click to Change</button>
```

Comment: @user8758206 glad to help.

Comment: Could also be done by `document.querySelector('.testBtn')` or `document.querySelectorAll('.testBtn')[0]` for the first element.

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByClassName("name") gives you an array, the first element of that array is your element. You need to do document.getElementByClassName[0] to get to the element. Try using document.querySelector instead.
Also , you can go to the web console to see whats happening to your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelector`:

```
function change() {
    var btnToChange = document.querySelector(".testBtn");
    btnToChange.innerHTML = "it changed!";
}
```

Or with `getElementsByClassName`:

```
function change() {
    var btnToChange = document.getElementsByClassName("testBtn")[0];
    btnToChange.innerHTML = "it changed!";
}
```

Note that `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are the methods of `document` and all elements, but `getElementsByClassName` is only of `document`.

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByClassName returns an array-like object of all DOM elements.
You can use document.querySelector or  document.getElementsByClassName()[0] to get the first element.

```
function change() {
  var btnToChange = document.querySelector(".testBtn");
  btnToChange.textContent= "it changed!";
}
```