# Unable to use variable - I guess I am just assigning the variable again?

Tags: javascript

When assigning the add(a, b) function to the displayText Variable it won't work when written as the comment on the last line below.

I assume it is because I am simply assigning the displayText variable a new value. Or?

How do I get around that issue?

```
var displayText = document.getElementById("display-text").innerHTML

function operate(operator, a, b) {
    if (operator === '+') {
        document.getElementById("display-text").innerHTML = add(a, b)
        // displayText = add(a, b)
```

Comment: You get a reference to the *element*, not a property of the element: `const tmp = document.getElementById('xxx'); tmp.innerHTML = add(a, b)`

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+innerHTML+stored+in+variable+doesn’t+change) of [Setting innerHTML: Why won't it update the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8196240/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
var displayText = document.getElementById("display-text").innerHTML
```

Is only getting a copy of the `innerHTML` stored in the variable, not a reference to the element's `innerHTML` property. So when you set the variable later, your only overriding the string in the variable, not the property of the element.

You need the line to be:

```
document.getElementById("display-text").innerHTML = add(a, b);
```

So that you can be setting the property.

**NOTES:**

- Now, you really shouldn't be using `innerHTML` when you can avoid it
  because it has security and performance implications. If there isn't
  any HTML in the string, you definitely shouldn't be using it and
  instead you should be using `.textContent`.
- In order to not have to scan the DOM over and over for the same
  element, it makes sense to find it once and get a reference to the
  element. That way, you can access the variable holding a reference to
  the element as often as you need to. This is what you were attempting
  to do with the property, but the property stores a string, whereas
  the element is an object.

  ```
    // Get a reference to the element, not properties of the element
    var displayText = document.getElementById("display-text"); 

    function operate(operator, a, b) {
      if (operator === '+') {
          // Now you can reference the element without searching for it again
          displayText.textContent = add(a, b)
  ```

This is also the better approach because now you can access the element variable and get any property of the element you want without having to scan for the element again:

```
displayText.textContent = "foo";
displayText.classList.add("foo)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to refactor your code to something like this

```
let displayText = document.getElementById("display-text")

function operate(operator, a, b) {
    if (operator === '+') {
        displayText.innerHTML = add(a,b)
```

You don't need to grab the element from your function every-time your function executes