# Javascript updating textContent

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue with updating text content, if I select the element with document.querySelector() then it works but if I store the element in an object then I can't seem to update it.

Example:

```
let player1 = {
    totalScore: 0,
    currentScore: 0,
    totalScoreBox: document.querySelector('#score--0').textContent,
    currentScoreBox: document.querySelector('#current--0').textContent
}

const updatePlayerScore = (player, value) => {
    player.totalScore += value;
    player.currentScore += value;
    player.currentScoreBox = parseFloat(player.currentScore); //Doesn't work
    document.querySelector('#current--0').textContent = parseFloat(player.currentScore); //Works
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Copopops/rsuc7m4g/1/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of [Setting innerHTML: Why won't it update the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8196240/4642212); the same applies to `textContent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `currentScoreBox: document.querySelector('#current--0').textContent` retrieves the textContent as a string, and stores that string in the `currentScoreBox` variable. When you set `currentScoreBox` to another string, all you are doing at that point is replacing the value of that variable, it is in no way attached to your DOM.

Instead, store the node itself.

```
let player1 = {
    totalScore: 0,
    currentScore: 0,
    totalScoreBox: document.querySelector('#score--0'),
    currentScoreBox: document.querySelector('#current--0')
}

const updatePlayerScore = (player, value) => {
    player.totalScore += value;
    player.currentScore += value;
    player.currentScoreBox.textContent = parseFloat(player.currentScore);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much that was bugging the crap out of me.