# if else is not working while making dice game in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, dice

I am doing a dice game challenge on my Udemy course using JavaScript.
Everything till now works fine, I made the dices to be random each time there's a reload.
I'm now trying to make the "h1" to change to "DRAW!","PLAYER 1 WINS!" and "PLAYER 2 WINS!" using `if else` statements.
But for some reason the `if else` won't respond. My Code:
HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dicee</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\natan\Desktop\Web Development udemy\JavaScript\Dicee Challenge\styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <h1 class ="h1">Refresh Me</h1>

      <div class="dice">
      <p>Player 1</p>
<img class="img1" src="C:\Users\natan\Desktop\Web Development udemy\JavaScript\Dicee Challenge\images\dice6.png" alt="dice6">
      </div>

      <div class="dice">
        <p>Player 2</p>
<img class="img2" src="C:\Users\natan\Desktop\Web Development udemy\JavaScript\Dicee Challenge\images\dice6.png" alt="dice6">
    </div>

    </div>



<script src="./js/index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>

  <footer>
    www  App Brewery  com
  </footer>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function randomDice() {

  const randomNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  const randomNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);

  const img1Random = document.querySelector(".img1");
  img1Random.setAttribute("src", "./images/dice" + randomNum1 + ".png");

  const img2Random = document.querySelector(".img2");
  img2Random.setAttribute("src", "./images/dice" + randomNum2 + ".png");

  let doch1 = document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML

  if (randomNum1 === randomNum2) {
    doch1 = "DRAW!"
  } else if (randomNum1 > randomNum2) {
    doch1 = "PLAYER 1 WINS!"
  } else {
    doch1 = "PLAYER 2 WINS!"
  }
}

randomDice()
```

Comment: doch1 is a string. Changing it does not change the .innerHTML property you read it from. That's not how primitive values work

Comment: Writing `doch1 =` does not change the HTML it just assigns a new value to the variable.

Comment: The problem is in doch1 variable. doch1 is just a usual variable, not a reference to element's innerHTML property, but its value. Try storing in variable only reference to dom node and then in you conditionals change its innerHTML

Comment: Add `document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = doch1;` after the else-if

Comment: `img1Random.setAttribute("src", "./images/dice" + randomNum1 + ".png");` would probably be easier to read as ``img1Random.src = `./images/dice${randomNum1}.png`;``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting innerHTML: Why won't it update the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196240/setting-innerhtml-why-wont-it-update-the-dom)

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dicee</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\natan\Desktop\Web Development udemy\JavaScript\Dicee Challenge\styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class ="h1">Refresh Me</h1>
      <div class="dice">
      <p>Player 1</p>
      <img class="img1" src="C:\Users\natan\Desktop\Web Development udemy\JavaScript\Dicee Challenge\images\dice6.png" alt="dice6">
      <p id="Player1Roll"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="dice">
        <p>Player 2</p>
        <img class="img2" src="C:\Users\natan\Desktop\Web Development udemy\JavaScript\Dicee Challenge\images\dice6.png" alt="dice6">
        <p id="Player2Roll"></p>
<p id="results"></p>
<button onclick ="randomDice()">Play Again!</button>
    </div>
    </div>
<script>
  function randomDice() {
  const randomNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  const randomNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
document.getElementById("Player1Roll").innerHTML = 'Player one rolled ' + randomNum1 + '!'
document.getElementById("Player2Roll").innerHTML = 'Player Two rolled ' + randomNum2 + '!'
  if (randomNum1 === randomNum2) {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "DRAW!"
  } else if (randomNum1 > randomNum2) {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "PLAYER 1 WINS!"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "PLAYER 2 WINS!"
  }
}
randomDice()
</script>
<h3 id="results"></h3>
  </body>

  <footer>
    www  App Brewery  com
  </footer>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

You probably already figured this out in an easier way but just in case here is the answer I came up with. :)